# Inline de múltiples elementos cuando el ancho es de 100%

Tags: css, html5, css3

tengo un listado de elementos para generar los breadcrums y cuando algún elemento es muy largo (en la imagen, el Elemento1, Elemento2 y Elemento 3 están dentro de un `li`) pasa a tener 100% por lo que se coloca en una nueva línea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber si es posible con CSS colocar eso a continuación del elemento anterior a este y cuando cambie a la próxima línea que empiece desde el principio... con una captura me explico mejor con lo que quiero conseguir :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con `display:inline` para todos los elementos pero nada y, en realidad, no estoy seguro si es posible hacerlo.

Dejo el enlace de [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmus0gar/5/) con el código por si queréis probar y el código aquí:

HTML

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="home" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <a itemprop="url" href="#" title="Go to Home Page">
      <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <a itemprop="url" href="#">
      <span itemprop="title">Shop</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
      <a itemprop="url" href="#">
        <span itemprop="title">Elemento número 1</span>
      </a>
    </span>, 
    <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
      <a itemprop="url" href="#">
        <span itemprop="title">Elemento número 2</span>
      </a>
    </span>, 
    <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
      <a itemprop="url" href="#">
        <span itemprop="title">Elemento número 3</span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>Elemento final</li>
</ul>
```

Y CSS:

```
.breadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.breadcrumb li:after {
  content: ' - ';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Mi pregunta es: ¿Necesitas obligatoriamente tener a los elementos número 1, número 2 y número 3 dentro del mismo li?

Comment: @PHPMyguel en principio sí ya que estos se generan a partir de un código ya existente que no he creado yo y que no quiero perder tiempo en modificar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el `li` con los 3 elementos es un solo objeto y se comporta como tal, tiene un tamaño fijo establecido por el total de sus componentes internos. Para solucionar tu actual problema solo tienes que modificar los atributos `display`:

`display: inline-block;` por `display: inline;` [Ejemplo 1](https://jsfiddle.net/jmus0gar/39/)

Esto anterior soluciona tu problema, pero si lo quieres todo en una linea sin que te haga el salto de linea utiliza en la clase `.breadcrumb` la propiedad `white-space: nowrap;` para que no te separe en lineas cuando encuentre un espacio en blanco [Ejemplo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/jmus0gar/19/), el problema está en que te quepa todo el breadcrumb en el espacio que tienes disponible, en tu caso supongo que no es posible :)